# Camel-sftp disable host verification globally

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp, spring-camel

I use Camel DSL route definition:

````
@Component
public class UploadRoutesDefinition extends RouteBuilder {
  ...
  @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    ```
        from(String.format("sftp://%s@%s:%d/%s?password=%s&delete=true&readLock=changed&delay=%s"
        ...
````

When I put file into sftp folder I see following logs:

````
20/03/2018 14:02:4420.03.18 14:02:44.193 [Camel (My_Service) thread #3 - seda://parsed_csv] INFO  o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations - Known host file not configured, using user known host file: /home/gradle/.ssh/known_hosts
20/03/2018 14:02:4420.03.18 14:02:44.300 [Camel (MIS_UploadService) thread #3 - seda://parsed_csv] WARN  o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations - JSCH -> Permanently added 'sftp' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
20/03/2018 14:02:4420.03.18 14:02:44.300 [Camel (MIS_UploadService) thread #3 - seda://parsed_csv] WARN  o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations - Server asks for confirmation (yes|no): /home/gradle/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist.
20/03/2018 14:02:44Are you sure you want to create it?. Camel will answer no.
```
````

I want to disable host verification.

Looks like adding `&useUserKnownHostsFile=false` to the path resolves my error. But I have a lot of route definitions and I don't like to add this suffix to each URL. Can I disable this verification globally?

Comment: why could add all the servers to `.ssh/known_hosts` file yourself, so that camel recognizes this as known host

Comment: @pvpkiran, client often changes the sftp server urls and don't want to do any manipulaion except  changing URL, login and password

Comment: how about looping on all sftp endpoints and use java api to disable it: ((SftpEndpoint)endpoint).getConfiguration().setUseUserKnownHostsFile(false)
to

Answer (score 1):

You cannot configure this globally. But as its java code its easy to use Camel's property placeholder to have a global ftp url you can use as base, or in your Camel route its also just Java code, so the string formatter you do, can use a base string that has the option turned on you then use with string concat etc.

Comment: can you please show example of camel property placeholer?

Comment: Read the docs at: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html